# How to have block in HTML where all open <B> and <I> are closed?

Tags: html, tags

I am automatically constructing `HTML` using fragments of `HTML` from other sources.

One of the fragments may contain an open `<I>` tag.  Is there away to have this fragment enclosed in a block so that the `<I>` doesn't affect further HTML.  I tried `<DIV>` but that doesn't work.

eg.

```
<DIV>
<I>Some Text
</DIV>
More Text
```

When the above is rendered in a browser, "More Text" is italic, which is what I don't want.

I thought of ending each block with `</B></I>`.  Is there tag in `HTML` that clears all formatting?

Answer (score 0):

try to close the italic tag`<i> </i>` tag

eg.

`<div>
<i>Italic Text</i>
</div>
Other Text`